# Implement a buffer of barcode readings in Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, android-asynctask, barcode

I'm developing an app that reads barcodes and for each barcode reading it executes a query.

I'm reading barcodes and executing queries correctly, but I need a buffer so if user scans barcodes very quickly, each query waits for the previous query to end and then process the next barcode. Here I explain my current implementation:

Queries are executed by an AsyncTask, so I can run the query, update UI in the OnPostExecute() method, and wait for the query to finish by using AsyncTask.Get() and AsyncTask.GetAsync() methods.

I use DispatchKeyEvent() method in order to process barcode readings (they are the same as pressed keys), and I have used this as solution for waiting for the previous AsyncTask to end before launching the next one:

```
public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
{
    // Only process key down and not key up events
    if (e.Action != KeyEventActions.Down)
        return true;

    // Here is the key of my current buffer, this event executes a Get() so it waits for the 
    // current AsyncTask to finish before continue execution and launching the next AsyncTask
    if (this.myAsyncTask != null && this.myAsyncTask.GetStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.Finished)
        this.myAsyncTask.Get();

    // Here I launch the next AsyncTask 
    // ...
}
```

The code above is working fine, but I feel it is slow, like if there were any conflict between the key event, the Get() of my AsyncTask and/or the UI update in the OnPostExecute.

Do you think anything is wrong? Is there another way to get the buffer work and launch my AsyncTask for each barcode reading waiting for the previous AsyncTask to end?

I'm new in Android so I prefer a simple solution as far as possible. I'm developing the app with Xamarin Android (not Xamarin Forms!), code and libraries are the same as Android Java.

Comment: How do you do the async? Have you tried to use async/await?

Comment: I just execute an Android AsyncTask using its methods for running in background and post execution https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask and I also use AsyncTask methods GetStatus() to detect if the AsyncTask is finished and Get() or GetAsync() to wait for the AsyncTask to end. That code is above, but my full AsyncTask code has a bundle of transactional queries and it is too long to share it here but it is working correctly.

Comment: Maybe youcould try to improve Xamarin.Forms App Performance. Check the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance

Comment: It is not a Xamarin Forms app, it is a Xamarin Android app, so I use Android libraries only, that's the reason I ask for help for Android @WendyZang-MSFT

Comment: Sorry, mine mistake. The document below would be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/performance

Comment: General advices, but no solution, I think there is any deadlock between my barcode (keys) reading, my UI updating and my SQL queries.

Comment: Check the link below about how to deect deadlock.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/april/avoiding-and-detecting-deadlocks-in-net-apps-with-csharp-and-c https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/october/net-matters-deadlock-monitor